# How to install Kaggle on Jupyter Notebook services in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, kaggle

I've using Google Colab for computing my Kaggle competition, nowadays I decided to take a look if it'll work faster using services on Google Cloud. I have a `*.ipybn` file from Google Cloud, downloaded it and try to upload it to Google Cloud instance.

I created all connection on Google Colab using this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-kaggle-in-google-colab-ebb281b61463 and it worked fine.

Using this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-jupyter-on-a-google-cloud-vm-5ba1b473f4c2 I started a new instance for Jupyter notebook. Uploaded a `*ipybn` file, I tried to install Kaggle and run my notebook, but I have usually following errors:

`kaggle: command not found error`
`ensure that your python binaries are on your path`

How can I set everything to work on Google Cloud service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this first tutorial mind about changing root directory path from `content` to `/home/jupyter/`, for example:

```
import zipfile
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("/home/jupyter/Airbus_competition/input/test_v2.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall("/home/jupyter/Airbus_competition/input/test_v2")
zip_ref.close()
```

For problems with installing kaggle, you don't have access to root folder from Jupyter notebooks, but you can install and use Kaggle API, when you change the command from `!kaggle` to `!~/.local/bin/kaggle`, for example (commands from tutorial changed to be working on GCS):

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle


import json
token = {"your_TOKEN"}
with open('/home/jupyter/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(token, file)!cp /home/jupyter/.kaggle/kaggle.json 


~/.kaggle/kaggle.json


!~/.local/bin/kaggle config set -n path -v{home/jupyter/Airbus_competition}


!chmod 600 /home/jupyter/.kaggle/kaggle.json


!~/.local/bin/kaggle competitions download -c airbus-ship-detection -p /home/jupyter/Airbus_competition/input --force
```